# Include multiple files using a wildcard and group them

Tags: c#

If you edit the .csproj file you can include files that are outside the project and match a wildcard.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="..\..\MyFolder\*.XML" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Those files will be displayed at the root of the project.

There's also a `Link` attribute that allows you to include a file but showing it in a different folder. You can even rename the files.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="..\..\MyFolder\1.XML" Link="Resources\Rename1.XML" />
  <None Include="..\..\MyFolder\2.XML" Link="Resources\Rename2.XML" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Is it possible to combine these two features? I mean, to include all the files that match the wildcard but at the same time set a different path, something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="..\..\MyFolder\*.XML" Link="Resources\$(FileName)"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

I couldn't find anything like that in the documentation. I've also tried some different alternatives that seemed logical to me but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="..\..\MyFolder\*.XML">
      <Link>Resources\%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

(or something similar)

Also note `%`